# Probability of observing harmonic oscillator at a particular position

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, harmonic-oscillator, velocity, probability

Consider a classical harmonic oscillator whose Hamiltonian is
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m} +\frac{1}{2}mw^2x^2$$
where $w$ is the oscillating frequency.

I wish to find the probability of observing the harmonic oscillator at a particular position $x$. This should be inversely proportional to the speed of the oscillator at $x$, i.e.

$$P(x)\propto \frac{1}{v(x)}.$$

If the amplitude of the oscillation is $x_0$, the speed of the harmonic oscillator at $x$  would be
$$v(x)=w(x_0^2 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Hence the probability of the oscillator being observed at $x$ is
$$P(x) \propto {1 \over w(x_0^2 - x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}.$$

There is one problem though. The probability to find $x=x_0$ would be infinite. Is there any way to work around this infinity?

Comment: How do you obtain $P \propto 1/v$ ?

Comment: @EmileCouzin it's a probability to find an oscillator in a region, if we look at arbitrary moment of time. Formally one could write the probability given the exact solution $x(t)=x_0\cos (\omega t+\phi)$ and then average over the initial phase $\phi$.

Comment: So you're not working with Kolmogorov laws ? Because if you do, $v$ needs to be in $]0, 1]$ which is quite weird for a speed (or maybe I did not understand what kind of "speed" is it ?)

Comment: @EmileCouzin not sure what you are referring to. $v=|\dot{x}|$ This kind of probability calculation is usually done in the context of establishing link between classical and quantum oscillators, you may google it up. I wouldn't look into it deeper than that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with continuous distributions, one should make difference between *probability* and *probability density*. Probability of hitting any specific point of a continuous distribution is zero, since the number of points in a continuum is infinite. Probability of getting a point in an interval $[x,x+\Delta x]$ is finite:
$$
P(x<X<x+\Delta x)=\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x}dxp(x)\approx p(x)dx
$$
Now, the oscillator probability density in the OP takes infinite values at the turning points, $x= \pm x_0$, however, it diverges at these points as $\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0-x}}$, that is the integral of this probability density is convergent.

One could also use the *cumulative distribution function*
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xdxp(x),
$$
which gives the probability of hitting any point smaller than $x$. The probability of hitting an interval is then
$$
P(x<X<x+\Delta x)=F(x+\Delta x) - F(x).
$$

In our case
$$
F(x)=\int_{-x_0}^xdxp(x)=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)
$$
(The normalization constant $w$ is fixed to $w=\pi$ by requirement that the full probability of hitting a point between $-x_0$ and $x_0$ is $F(x_0)=1$.)